# I'm getting crazy with this Promise stuff

Tags: promise

hope someone can help.
I am working on a translation part in magic mirror. I use the inside node_helper.js of a weather modul: Let me show u the code:

```
            if (this.config.lang != 'en'){
                console.log("in Translate");
                    translate(alerts.description, {to: this.config.lang}).then((res) => {console.log(res.text); return res;});
                    translate(alerts.expires, {to: this.config.lang}).then(res => {console.log(res.text)});
                translate(alerts.message, {to: this.config.lang}).then(res => {console.log(res.text)});
            }
```

and so on. If i look into config.log i get all results i love to see, but iam unable to use them in the following code ,,,, PLEASE HELP

Comment: By the way, the translate function is from google translate and returns a Promise

Comment: What is the problem that you want help with?

Comment: as i said, the output of the translate is correctly shown in console.log, but i need it in the code after the 3 translate calls and this is my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()` to coordinate when three operations that all return a promise are done and then use use those results in the resulting `.then()` callback:

```
        if (this.config.lang != 'en'){
            console.log("in Translate");
            Promise.all([
                translate(alerts.description, {to: this.config.lang}),
                translate(alerts.expires, {to: this.config.lang}),
                translate(alerts.message, {to: this.config.lang})
            ]).then(function(results) {
                // results[0], results[1], results[2] contain the three results
                // use those three values in the code inside this callback
            })
        }
```

Comment: thanks for helping. I tried ur code and thats what i get if do console.log("x=" , result[0]);   x=[object Object]

Comment: @RobertWeigerstorfer - You'd have to show me the actual code you tried.  My example uses `results[0]`, not `result[0]` like you show in your comment.

Comment: GREAT THANKS I forgot to say that the result is a json format so when i enter results[0].text i got the correct reply.

Comment: the forgotten 's' in results was only a typing error here. but it works now again many many thanks, i fighted with this ... since 1 week. how can i show u my thanks?